# How to modify php.ini configuration on NixOs?

Tags: nixos

I have a NixOS machine with Nginx and phpfpm. I can't figure how to set a value in php.ini.

I tried to do that :

```
services.phpfpm.phpIni = pkgs.runCommand "php.ini" {
    options = ''
      sendmail_path = "/run/wrappers/bin/sendmail -t -i"
    '';
  } ''
    cat ${pkgs.php}/etc/php-recommended.ini > $out
    echo "$options" >> $out
  '';
```

but I get the following message, and the file keeps unchanged :

```
warning: The option definition `services.phpfpm.phpIni' in
`configuration.nix' no longer has any effect; please remove it.
```

Is there another method to do this ?

Comment: Is `services.phpfpm.phpOptions` what you are looking for? Its description says *Options appended to the PHP configuration file php.ini.*

Comment: That's it, thank you! Meanwhile I also found this solution :
    ``` environment.etc."php.d/php.ini".text = ''
     sendmail_path = "/run/wrappers/bin/sendmail -t -i"
     date.timezone = Europe/Paris
   '';```
   But your solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Zimm-i48, you can change php settings using `services.phpfpm.phpOptions` configuration option:

```
services.phpfpm.phpOptions = ''
  extension=${apcu}/lib/php/extensions/apcu.so
  apc.stat = '0'
  apc.slam_defense = '0'
  etc...
'';
```

More options to discover: https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#services.php